# Trying to understand dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, traceback

I am playing about with Python, trying to understand dictionaries. I know questions have been asked before relating to this error, but they don't help me understand my issue.

I have the following code

```
mailSender = dict()
count = 0
name = input("Enter file:")
handle = open(name)
for line in handle:
    line = line.rstrip()
    if not line.startswith("From "):
        continue
    count = count + 1
    senderNames = line.split()
    # print(splitLines[1])
    print(senderNames[1])

    if senderNames not in mailSender:
        mailSender[senderNames] = 1
    else:
        mailSender[senderNames] = mailSender[senderNames] + 1

# print(mailSender)
```

I am trying to pick out email addresses for a text file,a nnd then find who sent the most emails.

I keep getting the following error:

```
if senderNames not in mailSender: TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

I do not have the experience to see where I am going wrong, and I hope someone can shed some light on it.

Comment: `senderNames` is a list. lists aren't hashable because they're mutable, and dict keys need to be hashable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A dictionary has 2 parts, `keys` and `values`. Each `key`, points to a `value`, which is done like so:

`mailSender["email@email.com"] = 5 # This means, that email@email.com appears 5 times`

When you are trying to look for the name of a sender, you need to search for the name in the `keys` where all the emails are stored, not the entire dictionary, which is a mapping for `keys` to `values`. You also need to indicate the position of the email address you want to find in `senderNames`, which is 1 of the list of emails. You can solve your problem, by changing your code to:

```
if senderNames[*index of name*] not in mailSender.keys():
    mailSender[senderNames] = 1
else:
    mailSender[senderNames] = mailSender[senderNames] + 1
```

For example, you could refer to finding the first email address like this:

```
if senderNames[0] not in mailSender.keys():
    mailSender[senderNames] = 1
else:
    mailSender[senderNames] = mailSender[senderNames] + 1
```

It will then search for if `senderNames` is in the keys of `mailSender`. Hope this helped!

Comment: Thanks! I think this has helped me move a bit further along!

Comment: You're welcome! If this has helped you, please consider accepting this answer with the checkmark on the left of the answer! @o.fithcheallaigh

Comment: I would upvote your answer too, if I could! But, as yet, I can't. Many thanks again!

Comment: That's alright, its not about upvotes, rather, it's about helping others understand!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're using senderNames, which is a list with the From and whatnot, whereas you are probably looking for senderNames[1], the name.  Something like this - though you might be wanting to combine some of the sender names array into a single string, not sure exactly what your data looks like.

```
for line in handle:
    line = line.rstrip()
    if not line.startswith("From "):
        continue
    count = count + 1
    senderNames = line.split()
    print(senderNames[1])
    name = senderNames[1]

    if name not in mailSender:
        mailSender[name] = 1
    else:
        mailSender[name] = mailSender[name] + 1
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, and your explanation!